# Control Tower is not starting in my Work Fusion RPA Express

Tags: automation, rpa, workfusion

I have installed WorkFusion RPA Express on my machine with Windows 7 Operating System.
I am even able to record things and run them successfully.
But when I want to open the Control Tower, I go to start the Control Tower from the menu box.
But after multiple attempts it is not starting or running.
What can be the issue or What things to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even I've faced that issue, you need to make sure you have atleast 4gb ram free for it startup. My laptop is having 8gigs ram, but I had to stop my other RAM heavy processes, then it got started. Else it used to go one a starting up loop and never start. If even what i suggested doesn't help, try re-installing the workfusion package.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to this answer, sometimes when starting control tower the browser window opens up successfully but control tower login page would not appear.

In this case, you can type: [localhost:15280/workfusion/login](http://localhost:15280/workfusion/login) manually to get the control tower login page. Instead of restarting CT again and again, this will resolve such issue faster.